# Captura del value tras perder el foco del elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Que tal necesito obtener el value de los elementos del dom en cuanto pierdan el foco.
Tengo un formulario creado con javascript por lo que hago uso del onClick para capturar el Id del elemento clickeado para posteriormente ponerlo en la funcion blur, de esta manera:

```
    var idRespuesta;
    $(function() {
        $('body').on('click','.respuestas',function(){
             idRespuesta = $(this).attr('id');           
        })
    })
```

Despues de eso espero a que se pierda el foco

```
$(function(){
        try{
            $(idRespuesta).blur(function(){
                alert(idRespuesta);
                $(this).css("border-color", "#33ff58");
                let aux = $(this).val();
                alert(aux);
            });
        }catch(error){
            alert(error);
        }
    })
```

Pero no obtengo respuesta de nada de las funciones tras perder el foco del elemento,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo mismo respondo a mi pregunta, no tenia tal cual un disparador el metodo blur,lo solucione agregando el segundo metodo dentro del onclick y añadiendo un auxiliar con el `#` propio de los id´s
Dejo la solucion que encontre

```
    var idRespuesta;
    var auxIdRespuesta;
    $(function() {
        $('body').on('click','.respuestas',function(){
             idRespuesta = $(this).attr('id');
             auxIdRespuesta = "#"+idRespuesta;

             try{
                $(auxIdRespuesta).blur(function(){
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#33ff58");
                    let aux = $(this).val();
                    alert(aux);
                });
            }catch(error){
                alert(error);
            }
        })
    })
```